# Is the following case of std::move superfluous?

Tags: c++, move

Is the following case of `std::move` superfluous?

```
std::string member;

obj(std::initializer_list<std::string> p_list)
    : member {std::move(join(p_list))}
{}
```

This is the join function:

```
std::string join(string_initializer_list p_list) {
    size_t size {};
    for (auto const & s : p_list) {
        size += s.size();
    }
    std::string output;
    output.reserve(size);
    for (auto const & s : p_list) {
        output.append(s);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: What is `join`?

Comment: I edited the question ;)

Comment: In which scenarios would the std::move be useful than?

Comment: `std::move` is useful when you have an lvalue that you want to treat as an rvalue, usually for purposes of resource-stealing. In your code, `join` returns an rvalue already, so there is no lvalue to give special treatment.

Comment: @DagobertoPires: If your constructor accepted a `std::string` as an argument by value, it would be named; you'd have to use `std::move` to avoid the copy in that case.

Comment: So, things like `A(A && a) : m {std::move(a.m)}` - the `&&` indicates that we want to use this constructor to catch rvalues, then, since `a` members are lvalues, we need to turn them into rvalues in order from them to be changed in `a`, a sort of cut/paste situation? Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need `std::move`. The function of `std::move` is to cast any value to an rvalue. Your function already returns an rvalue, thus the cast has no effect as far as binding the result to a reference is concerned (which is what you're after in order to initialize `member` from an rvalue).

In fact, using `std::move` actively *inhibits* copy elision, so it is a strict pessimization:

```
std::string s = join({});             // construct from prvalue, elidable,
                                      // elision mandatory in C++17

std::string s = std::move(join({}));  // temporary object must be constructed,
                                      // s is initialized by moving from the
                                      // temporary
```

In the first form, `std::string s = join({});`, copy elision means that the returned object of `join` is constructed directly in place of `s` (no temporary objects is constructed and copy or move is made), and moreover, the `output` variable in the function body is also elided and constructed directly in the return value, i.e. in `s`. With `std::move`, the first elision step is not available.

Comment: @erip: No, that's a different situation: that's if you said `return std::move(output)` in the function body. Interestingly, the argument there is seeminlgy the opposite: `output` is indeed an lvalue, but for reasons of special magic it is actually treated as an rvalue in that situation.

Comment: @erip: I think you're making a good point for C++17, though: Converting a prvalue to an xvalue (which is what `std::move` really does) may constitute a materialization conversion that breaks mandatory copy elision. But I'd have to check the details.

Comment: @erip: Actually, the move *does* pessimze here, but not because of RVO. Updating.

Comment: What about this idiom: `Obj(std::string p_data) : data {std::move(p_data)}`? They say that if it's an lvalue I will have a copy and a move and if it's an rvalue I will have two moves. Does that mean that if it's an lvalue, the string would first be copied into p_data and then copied into data and then the value of p_data would be "destroyed"? In order for std::move to leave an object in a sort of zombie state does it call like clear on the string?

Comment: @DagobertoPires: There are details here about whether you have an xvalue or a prvalue. If the argument is a prvalue, the construction of `p_data` is elidable (mandatory in C++17), and only the move from `p_data` to `data` is needed. If the argument is an xvalue, you have two mandatory moves. If the argument is an lvalue, you have one copy and one move.

Comment: So, is that idiom like the best in terms of convenience?

Comment: @DagobertoPires: (The lifetime of `p_data` is as for any function parameter. Moved-from objects are in their usual "valid-but-unspecified" state.)

Comment: @DagobertoPires: Yes, the idiom is great for leaf code. In highly reusable library code (where you don't know your users) it's worth writing two separate reference overloads instead to avoid the mandatory move, but if you know that it won't matter, then the by-value-and-move idiom is much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Given your `join` function is sane, and returns `std::string`, yes, the `std::move` would be superfluous; the return from `join` is an r-value already.

Beyond that, w/o `std::move`, copy elision means that it could construct the result in place without `std::move`, while using `std::move` could force it make a temporary `string`, invoke the move constructor to initialize `member`, then destroy the temporary; not a lot of work (a few pointer copies largely), but more than you need to do.

Comment: @DagobertoPires: And I edited the answer to remove the qualifications on my statements. :-)

Comment: In which scenarios would the std::move be useful than? I'm curious about this.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity: any function that returns by value and hence returns an rvalue does not need std::move to be applied, and as others have already pointed out it is detrimental to performance optimisations.

e.g.

```
SomeClass fn()
{
...
}

// Move not needed, detrimental, as the function result is already an rvalue
SomeClass x = std::move(fn());
```

just do this as usual before c++11:

```
SomeClass x = fn();
```

Generally speaking use std::move(x) when x has a name. i.e. it is an identifier, it is not useful on temporaries except for special circumstances (in which you want to prevent copy elision, for example)

On a side note: Also don't try to use std::move to force the "strong exception gurantee" (for example when you want a struct wholly copied or left alone [i.e. consisent] in the face of potential exceptions.) as std::move can throw depending on the moved type and this type's exception policy can change under you. Instead use a wrapper function with a static assert combined with noexcept to enfore this at compile time. See [Is there facility for a strong guaranteed exchange in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088173/is-there-facility-for-a-strong-guaranteed-exchange-in-c/42145609#42145609)