# Is there facility for a strong guaranteed exchange in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I have been looking for a facility to exchange two items with a strong exception guarantee. That is; to have the exchange proceed totally, or leave the target in the initial state in the face of exceptions. Is there anything included in the current standard that allows this, I have not been able to find anything, although it appears easy to write.

What I have below is a version I put together to try out what I am looking for, however it is noexcept, which is more than my requirement of "the strong" guarantee. Is appears the "strong guarantee" cannot be tested, but the noexcept guarantee can.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Guarantee to exchange l and r fully
// or (not compile) leave them in the initial state
template<typename T>
void strong_exchange(T & l, T &r) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    static_assert( noexcept( swap(l, r) ), "Types must be noexcept swappable");
    swap(l, r);
}

struct X
{
    X()
    {
        throw "fish";
    }

    X(X &&) = delete;
};

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    strong_exchange(a, b);

    X i, j;
    strong_exchange(i, j);
}
```

Comment: have you seen std::swap?

Comment: The absence of `noexcept`, or a specifier of `noexcept(false)`,  means that a function potentially throws.

Comment: @Peter - which is fine as long as it leaves the items in their origional state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably impossible:**

It is impossible if copy assignment is not `noexcept` (or other way to perform the copy). In case it is `noexcept`, `std::swap()` should do the thing. Otherwise, there is probably nothing one can do about it.

Comment: your answer is the most relevant (and only answer), but I want to point out that "provided swap" - this is irrelevant. I don't want to improve performance, I just want a way to exchange two items that will result in a consistent state and I want this guranteed at compile time. It seems at the moment from what you say that this is only possible by using a custom exchange (I called it exchange on purpose) that includes a static assert. And it also seems no such facility already exists in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

@Incomputable has highlighted the problem, but I am including an answer for completeness.

- There is a class you want to assign but want to make sure there is a
  strong guarantee that it will be copied completely or not at all in
  the face of exceptions.. The only feasible solution therefore appears
  to be a static assert check at compile time to make sure that this
  will happen. Using std::move is not a guarantee since it can call a
  copy constructor which may throw, and may also fail to provide the
  all or nothing guarantee.
- In my specific case it is a set of configuration objects which must
  always be    valid, and since I can’t guarantee that without checking
  all the    objects manually and hoping the implementors can provide
  that    guarantee, I have written a noecept_assign function which
  should    ensure that is the case going forward. A complete example
  follows.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <type_traits>
>
> // Guarantee to exchange l and r fully or not compile.
> template<typename T>
> void noexcept_swap(T & l, T &r) noexcept
> {
>     using std::swap;
>     static_assert( noexcept( swap(l, r) ), "Types must be noexcept swappable");
>     swap(l, r);
> }
>
> // Guarantee to full assign r to l or not compile.
> template<typename T>
> void noexcept_assign(T & l, T r) noexcept
> {
>     noexcept_swap(l, r);
> }
>
> struct Exchangeable
> {
>     Exchangeable() { }
>
>     // C++ std::swap requires these two for now thorw, so noexcept_swap will also need them
>     Exchangeable(Exchangeable &&) noexcept { }
>     Exchangeable & operator=(Exchangeable &&) noexcept { }
>
>     // for noexcept_assign these is also required, since a copy is made durring assignment    Exchangeable(Exchangeable &) noexcept { }
>     Exchangeable & operator=(const Exchangeable &) noexcept { }
> };
>
> // This class is the same as the above, but it does not have
> // a noexcept guarantee on the methods
> struct NotExchangeable
> {
>     NotExchangeable()  {}
>     NotExchangeable(NotExchangeable &&) {}
>     NotExchangeable & operator=(NotExchangeable &&) { }
>
>     NotExchangeable(const NotExchangeable &) { }
>     NotExchangeable & operator=(const NotExchangeable &) { }
> };
>
> int main(void)
> {
>     int a, b;
>     noexcept_swap(a, b); // OK
>     noexcept_assign(a, b); // OK
>
>     Exchangeable i, j;
>     i = j; // Might throw and fail to do a full copy. Depends.
>     noexcept_swap(i, j); // OK
>     noexcept_assign(i, j); // OK
>
>     NotExchangeable x, y;
> #if 0
>     noexcept_swap(x, y); // Fails to compile and emits assertion
>     noexcept_assign(x, y); // Fails to compile and emits assertion
> #endif
> }
> ```